# Creating a new file in a new ext4 file system

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I've created and mounted an ext4 file system using:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
sudo mkdir /ext4_filesystem
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb  /ext4_filesystem
```

Now I'm trying to create a file in this file system using:

```
sudo ./mycode "~/ext4_filesystem/2.txt"
```

where the argument of "mycode" is the location of the file I want to create. The following line in "mycode" returns `fd < 0`. Where is the problem?

```
fd = open(argv[1], O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXG);
```

Comment: if you want to find out why `fd < 0`, evaluate `errno`, and/or use [`strerror()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strerror.html) and/or [`perror()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/perror.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "~" should not be there. You mounted `/ext4_filesystem`, not `~/ext4_filesystem`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no directory called "`~`". If you want the shell to expand `~` into your home directory, don't put it in quotation marks.